# Honorific for the dead for use in articles published online

Tags: honorifics

I'm writing an essay that I intend to publish online. The essay is about the Unix operating system, and I'm referencing an article published by a principal author - Dennis M. Ritchie who passed away in 2011.

What words or phrases can I use? For example, if I uses "dear old" I'd write something like this:

> In his paper "title", dear old Dennis Ritchie told us that ...

Except that "dear old" seems like something one'd use only within family members.

Comment: You might give ‘the late’ a shot, but in this particular case I am sure Dennis would prefer your phrasing. Excellent question!

Comment: Is it a formal paper in an academic journal, corporate website, etc, in which "dear old" would be inappropriate, or something on your own blog/website?

Comment: @StuartF It's a technical review on my GitHub page.

Comment: This might well be on-topic at Interpersonal Skills.SE.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you sure? This is a written document rather than a speech.

Comment: Yes. 'Except that "dear old" seems like something one'd use only within family members' shows that the request is for **socially acceptable** usage/s. And 'The question begs opinions rather than definitive answer. ' makes it doubly off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question begs opinions rather than definitive answer. I suggest the use of “dear old” within the context of an account of an operating system would appear patronising and incongruous unless you had first given substantial  evidence of a warm and engaging personality who was directly connected to you. Otherwise, it reads as if you are  claiming the glory of a personal connection you may not have had. You could  use “the late”, “the late beloved” or “the esteemed late” to better effect.